# Angular: chart.js chart is not displaying

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am using Angular, I have installed the `chart.js` but the chart is not displaying in the page.

Here is my code :

**dasboard.component.html**

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js'

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

when I do

```
console.log('hello');
```

in `dashboard.component.t`s, it is printing in console, but the graph is not displaying how can I solve this?

Comment: Is there any console error in the developer window?

Comment: If you're stuck, enjoy this tutorial. https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-chartjs/

Comment: @ArunRajR there is no error...it is not displaying anything

Comment: I think you can use a better alternative of Angular chart framework specially developed for angular projects [ngx charts] https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/bar-vertical

you can find it also on github https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, simply include the `canvas` into a `div` and it will display.

```
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n68tdt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard.component.html)